# polytime approximability of directed multicut

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, approximation, max-flow-min-cut

Does anyone know how well directed multicut can be approximated in planar and minor free graphs?  Also any survey of approximability of directed multicut and multicut in various graph classes would be appreciated  Also if anyone can recommend

Comment: As far as I know nothing better than general graph results are known for planar directed multicut other than in some very special cases. An important open problem.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri  could you elaborate on the very special cases?  I assume that the general graph result your refering to is  the logn loglogn of  G.  Even,  J.  (Seffi)  Naor,  B.  Schieber,  and  M.  Sudan.   Approximating  minimum  feedback  sets  andmulticuts in directed graphs?